# Compare 2014 to 1998, 2014 has a 90% chance of being warmer than 1998?

Tags: probability

According to NASA, 2014 has a 38% chance of being the warmest year, 1998 has only a 4% chance of being the warmest year.

2014 or 1998 have a 42% chance of being the warmest year.

Since I eliminated all other possibilities, I changed 42% to 100%.

42 * (100/42) = 42,
38 * (100/42) = 90,
 4 * (100/42) = 9.5

So, does 2014 have a 90% of being warmer than 1998? Please help 
what I am doing wrong?

[image: pr]

Comment: The probability you give for 1998 is an *a priori* expection - that's not of much interest now that the actual global temperatures for 1998 are known. The *a priori* calculation of whether 2014 was going to be warmer than 1998 would use *actual* 1998 results and a *modelled spread* of expected 2014 results.

Comment: It must exist a text, which explains the context of the two tables. Please post it.

Comment: http://www.factcheck.org/2015/04/obama-and-the-warmest-year-on-record/

Comment: http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/energy-environment/wp/2015/01/23/sorry-skeptics-nasa-and-noaa-were-right-about-the-2014-temperature-record/